# Aspell can't detect dictionaries in Emacs24 on Windows 7

Tags: dictionary, emacs, aspell, flyspell

I'm getting this error when I run Flyspell spell-checker in GNU Emacs 24.4.1 (i686-pc-mingw32) on Windows 7 (32 bits).

> Error in post-command-hook (flyspell-post-command-hook): (error "No data for dictionary \"italian"\ , neither in *ispell-local-dictionary-alist'* nor in *ispell-dictionary-alist'* ")

Here are the parts of my *.emacs* file that concern Aspell and Flyspell.

```
(setq-default ispell-program-name "aspell")

 (add-to-list 'exec-path "C:/Program Files/Aspell/bin/")

 (setq ispell-dictionary "italian") ; do M-x ispell-change-dictionary RET to change dictionary
```

I looked for possible solutions to this problem on Google but couldn't understand the problem in the first place since I'm not well-versed in the use of Emacs – I've only started using it a month ago.

Could it be some conflict with YASnippett 0.8.0? The spell-checker used to work fine upto a ~2 weeks ago, then I installed YASnippet via Elpa `M-x list-packages`, customized it for Org-mode and AUCTeX (the 2 modes I use), found and solved a conflict b/w YASnippet and Org-mode as instructed by the manual and now this… Can anyone give me a hint?

Comment: Did you install the Italian language module?:  `aspell-it-0.50-2-3.exe`  You may also wish to eliminate the potential PATH issue by using an absolute path for the `ispell-program-name` -- e.g., `(setq ispell-program-name "c:/Program Files/Aspell/bin/aspell.exe")`

Comment: Yes, I first installed `Aspell-0-50-3-3-Setup.exe` then the English and Italian dictionaries (double clicked on the respective .exe files). My path to Aspell is `C:\Program Files\Aspell`. The README file in the 'doc' folder says to add an environment variable called ASPELL_CON in case Aspell is not in `C:/Aspell` or import `aspell.reg`. What do I do? After changing to the absolute path as you suggested, I now get the message "No data for dictionary "italian", neither in ispell-local-dictionary-alist' nor in ispell-dictionary-alist' ". Any other strategy?

Comment: See my answer here, may help: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/38162/ispell-cant-find-my-dictionary